# Expired time doesn't work in ASP.Net Core

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, authorization

https://github.com/NanaseRuri/LibraryDemo/tree/Failed

I have already set the expired time in my ASP.Net Core project but it doesn't work. After 8 seconds I could still enter the action with `[Authorize]`.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal,new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(8)
});
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
});
```

Authentication:

```
if (admin.Password == encryptedPassword)
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity("Cookie");
    identity.AddClaims(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, admin.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, admin.Email),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, admin.PhoneNumber),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"),
    });

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(8)
    });

    if (returnUrl != null)
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the following! I have tested with this and it works perfectly.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // Set your expiration time here


    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
});
```

Make `options.SlidingExpiration = true;` if you want no expiration as long as logged in user is active.

Comment: Thanks! Help a lot! It just seems that the Identity framework set the Cookie.HttpOnly with false.

Comment: @NanaseRuri This is not the issue. `options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;` is for security. Expiration time is related to `options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);`

Comment: Yes, my problem was solved perfectly! I just confused that the code--options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true doesn't exist  in Microsoft document.                                           https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1#absolute-cookie-expiration

Comment: Great to hear that! Thank you.